# Validate datatype of operands in a mathematical expression

Tags: c#, database

I have to create a mathematical expression with column object as operands and validate the datatype of the operands. The column object represents a database column and consists of table name, column name and datatype. If the operand datatype is `text` or `bool` an error message should be displayed. How can this validation be done?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to vary based on what database engine you are using, but for SQL Server, you could use this query to load column shema data to compare against:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: ((column1 + column2)/column3) is an expression that i need to validate.column1,column2 & column3 are 3 column objects(c# objects) and it stores the datatype as string.i need to compare the data types using the column object.

Comment: When you say "is an expression" does that mean you have a string value equaling "((column1 + column2)/column3)"? Then your problem is about parsing that text into an abstract syntax tree, or at least tokenizing the text into token sequence. Once you have that, you can walk the AST or tokens to match them up with your column objects, check the datatype and react accordingly.